# PHP multiple values in regex + wildcards

Tags: php, regex

I just want to stress that I've been reading, trying and failing a lot before I asked this question. I can see similar questions but not exact duplicates.

I need to find a value that:

- Could be in any case.
- Could or could not end with something completely random E.g. "Cake is yummy"
- May or may not be enclosed in /slashes/

This is what I'm currently doing:

> ```
>   if ( $name == '/cake/' || $name == '/CAKE/' || $name == '/Cake/' || $name == '/CaKe/' || $name == 'CAKE' || $name == 'cake' {
> ```

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
if(preg_match == (cake:) *(\([a-zA-Z]+\).+){
```

Can't quite get it to work.

Comment: Do you have regexp enclosed in quotes?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to make the string uppercase first and then do `$name = strtoupper($name); if($name == '/CAKE/' || $name == 'CAKE') {`?

Comment: I think you need to be much more detailed in what you are trying to match. Is it just single words? What do you mean it may end with random stuff? Should that be matched as well? Etc. When working with regular expressions you need to to very specific in what you want and what you do *not* want.

Comment: Still doesn't account for random strings after

Comment: @Cyclone If it can be in any case then a case-**in**sensitive match would do just fine. There is no reason to uppercase it.

Comment: There could be a few words after that may be anything, I just need to find "cake" or "/cake/" etc. + Anything afterwards.

Comment: But it has to include the word `cake`? If this is the case, then you could use something like this: `/cake/i`

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen - I know that, I was only pointing out that the original if statement could be shortened by make the string uppercase.

Comment: @Cyclone Ah. My bad.

Comment: Do you need only to match or do you need to replace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're basically searching for a case-insensitive `Cake`. Then just use the [`i` flag](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).

```
  preg_match("~ Cake ~xi", $name)
                       ↑
```

If you also want to match for optional `/` slashes around, then add an altenative:

```
  preg_match("~ /Cake/  |  \b Cake \b ~xi", $name)
                ↑    ↑      ↑       ↑
```

Note the `\b` word boundary markers for the unenclosed cake, so you're not matching `Cakeriky` for example.

1. If you want `Cake` to be at the start of the string, then it'll need an [`^` marker](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.anchors.php).

   ```
    preg_match("~ ^  (/Cake/  |  \b Cake \b) ~xi", $name)
                  ↑
             start anchor
   ```
2. If you additionally wanted to *enforce* some text thereafter being present (and not optional/ignored), then add another placeholder:

   ```
    preg_match("~ ^  (/Cake/  |  \b Cake \b)   .*\w.* ~xi", $name)
                                                  ↑
                                         at least one word char
   ```

Comment: Thanks, how about if I wanted to match '/cake/ - bake some!' for example, it could be anything afterwards

Comment: so for example: `if  $name preg_match("~ /Cake/  |  \b Cake \b ~xi",){` Would find cake, /cake/, cake is yummy, /cake/ is great etc. ?

Comment: Any combination of that. Add the `$name` parameter to match against.

Comment: Thanks for all your help can you just check my syntax here I'm unsure how to incorporate it 
Something like:
`if ($name == (preg_match("~ /Cake/ | \b Cake \b ~xi",)){`
Or

`if(preg_match("~ /Cake/ | \b Cake \b ~xi", $name))`

Comment: No. `$name ==` doesn't belong there. It's a `preg_match` param. You get a boolean result. Check the [manual examples](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php#refsect1-function.preg-match-examples). - The second variant is correct.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help  and patience :)